# Cannot reach some WEB pages

Tags: networking, firefox, firewall

A few weeks ago I was able to browse any WEB page from FireFox on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop system. Now some WEB pages time out. For example, no problem accessing askubuntu.com, but I time out trying to reach one of my own WEB pages hosted on GoDaddy (for example http://magic.kayaker.net/Terrain/). If I plug my Windows 10 laptop into my same LAN next to this Ubuntu system, the laptop can reach any WEB page, including the Terrain one above. This makes me think it is a local firewall problem on my Ubuntu system. How can I undo this?

Comment: You say undo so what did you do?

Comment: `UFW` is disabled by default. If you've enabled it, run `sudo ufw status verbose`. If not enabled, you can use use `iptables`.

Comment: Does this happen only with with non-HTTPS websites? 

Comment: Also, try a plain `curl <url>` to rule out any issues with Firefox.

Comment: What did I do? I don't know, only that something has changed. Perhaps the problem happened when I updated my certs after the CA cert problem. I've tried looking at the problem pages with Chrome, it has the same issue. I tried curl and the first time it worked, but when I tried it a second time it timed out. Every once in a while Firefox or Chrome is able to display that page.

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem with FTP, filezilla times out on some sites it used to work on, and just works fine on other ftp sites. My Windows 10 laptop can still get to all of them.

Comment: And now my email client times out and cannot read my emails. It keeps trying and every once in a while it downloads a bunch of emails. And I am able to read some http: WEB sites all the time, I have not found an https:// page that I cannot read.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed by changing my DNS Nameserver! By default Ubuntu set this to the IP address of my router. On desktop Ubuntu you can change this in Settings>Network, Click on the little gear icon on your wired connection, in the IPv4 tab change the DNS to 8.8.8.8 , 8.8.4.4  Reboot the computer and now my email and WEB pages work all the time.
8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are DNS Nameservers from Google.